# Should I do anything about very wrong closures?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, dupehammer

A user single-handedly (I didn't know that was even possible) closed [Sanitize all scripts from html string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301617/sanitize-all-scripts-from-html-string) as a duplicate of [Escaping HTML strings with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery).

Even by merely reading the titles, those are *very* obviously different. The first question has no mention of HTML escaping or jQuery *at all*.

A lot of duplicates require at least some degree of subjectively, but I see no possible defensible explanation for this. Likely, the user just had a few misfires of the ol' neurons.

Should I just chalk this up to a careless mistake and move on, or do something else? I have no idea whether it is a pattern. If it were, I suppose it would be worse.

Comment: *Don't put meta comments in your posts.*  That's what comments are for.

Comment: You should also be explaining *why* it's not a duplicate, not just saying *that* it's a duplicate.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, thanks. I just wanted the comment...you know...at the top...where the duplicate note is ;) But okay.

Comment: I reopened your question, but since a gold-badge holder duped it, they clearly thought that your answer could be found there, so you might want to actually read the original post to see what it contains.  I can't tell you how many times I've linked something because I knew it had helpful information for the OP, only to find out that they never bothered to even look at it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey In this case the post would technically have solved the problem, but cause a bunch more.  Paul was asking how to strip out executable code from HTML, and was linked to a post that escapes all HTML code to be plain text.  Technically that would ensure there is no executable code, but also strip out all non-executable HTML code too.

Comment: @PaulDraper If you wanted to comment or edit your question, see my previous comment for something that you could have said that would explain why it's not a duplicate post.