# Can (and should) I do anything about bad rejection reasons of bad edits?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

While going through the review queue, I found several edits by the same user that were all of the "add backticks around some words" variety. I rejected a few as "No improvement whatsoever", others I was inclined to accept. But what I noticed as I was rejecting many of them was that they already had one rejection vote, but that rejection vote had given "Attempt to reply" as the reason.

Now, I was inclined to agree with the idea that this edit should be rejected. But they were CLEARLY not attempts to reply. After the third such edit that I saw, I started to suspect that some previous reviewer had been powering through the review queue rejecting everything with the same "Attempt to reply" reason, just for the sake of accumulating "points" towards the Reviewer badge. (I put "points" in quotation marks because "number of review tasks completed" is not *per se* a points score, but it's still a number that goes up and gives you a prize at the end.)

So, two questions:

1. Is there anything that I (as someone with just barely over 4k reputation at this time) **can** do about those bad review votes by an earlier reviewer?
2. If there is anything that I can do, **should** I? Or should I just vote the way I think is correct, and trust that the reason reported to the editor whose edits were rejected will end up being "No improvement whatsoever" instead of "Attempt to answer"? (I don't actually know how the rejection reason gets determined -- majority/plurality of rejection-reason votes? First rejection reason "wins"? I don't know where to go to find that out.)

If some or all of this question has already been answered earlier in Meta, I apologize for the duplicate, and can only say that my searching attempts so far were insufficient to find the answer to my question. (I found questions like [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285249/should-i-do-anything-about-very-wrong-closures), but they're about closing duplicate questions, not about rejecting edits). Also, I'd appreciate any pointers to what I should be doing as a reviewer -- I haven't found that either. I've found FAQs on "Here's how you should behave as a *user* of the site", but I've been unable to find any FAQs on "Here's how you should behave as a *reviewer* with more power than the average user." Any links to such documents would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:** [Are suggested edit reviewers ping-able from comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262707/are-suggested-edit-reviewers-ping-able-from-comments) tells me one thing that I can do, so it partially answers the first part of my question. (I don't think it fully answers it, since I can't tell from that question whether there's anything else I could do). But it doesn't answer the second part of my question, whether I *should* do anything like contacting the other reviewer. I don't think this is exactly a duplicate question of that one, though it's certainly *close*.

Comment: Since an example might help, one of the edits I was referring to was http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10271107, which has now been approved by a 3-2 vote. (I paused while reviewing it to go ask this question, and while I was posting this, it received its second rejection followed by its third acceptance vote. If I had actually rejected it before posting this question, the edit would have ended up rejected by a 3-2 vote instead. So my inaction ended up changing the outcome.)

Comment: Man the title threw me off a little. You're talking about bad rejection *reasons*, not bad rejections :)

Comment: @Gimby - Hmm, yes, I see I did misphrase it a little. Corrected the title.

Comment: Probably a duplicate indeed. It has to go as far as diamond mods taking a personal interest for anything to really be done: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302450/424903 .

Comment: @CodeCaster: Seriously? rmunn's question may well be a duplicate, but it's not a duplicate of *that*. They aren't even that strongly related, in my opinion. It's not like OP is asking to communicate with the reviewer, or even to find out who the reviewer is. These things, if they are possible at all, *might* be ways to go about handling the situation. In effect, your "possible duplicate" is a comment, a followup question, or even a pseudo-answer to OP's question.

Comment: @John the answer is _"nothing"_. You cannot directly do anything. You can roll back the edit after it's approved. That too is addressed in other Q&As on meta, but I can't really find those right now.

Comment: @CodeCaster - Thanks for the link, which I couldn't find in my search. That explains *what* I could do, or at least one option. I don't think it fully answers my question, though since it doesn't tell me whether I *should* contact the reviewer whose opinion I disagree with. That point of etiquette is something I'm wondering about too, since I'm pretty new to the edit-review process.

Comment: @CodeCaster: That's fine. Then make that your answer. Don't vote to close this question.

Comment: Sorry, rmunn. Apparently the close-voters of your question take the same care in their actions as the reviewers that just robo-reject everything with "attempt to reply". :P

Comment: Eh, there are three reopen votes at this point (counting the one I just cast), and I've edited my question to explain why I don't think it's a duplicate. We'll see if anyone else agrees.

Comment: More mods, I tell ye. *MORE MODS*

Comment: Usually "adding backticks around some words" may significantly improve question readability. As a reviewer I would rather accept such edit.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny [I expect that that is sarcasm...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137755/213575)

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny - Sometimes I've accepted edits that just add backticks, if they were backticks that actually made sense. (E.g., function and variable names from the OP's posted code). But most of what I was seeing during that edit session were backticks that harmed legibility, like changing Angular to `Angular` when the word referred to the AngularJS library, not an identifier in the code named `Angular`. I believe backticks should be reserved for code-ish things, not project names and other human-readable things. Hence why I was planning to reject that particular edit and others like it.

Answer (score 6):

To start with, you're not so concerned about the reject reason itself. You are concerned that this user is a robo reviewer:

> After the third such edit that I saw, I started to suspect that some previous reviewer had been powering through the review queue rejecting everything with the same "Attempt to reply" reason, just for the sake of accumulating "points" towards the Reviewer badge

So the real question is, "What do I do about a suspected robo reviewer?"

And the answer comes from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171872)

> Flag one of their posts with a custom flag, asking for a mod to look into it. Mods can't review ban (the mod will have to ask the Community Team for that), but they can send a warning to the user.
>   I have a few doubts/concerns that what I'm about to say isn't the accepted norm, but I will let the votes decide. If any mods wish to confirm, I'd appreciate a comment.

Comment: -1; this shouldn't be the first course of action given the OP's situation. Reviews are public; if you've just stumbled across one or two dodgy-looking reviews by a user, you should look through their review history in their profile to confirm your suspicions before bringing it to a mod. Maybe they just screwed up the cases you happened to see.

Comment: If there's general consensus on this answer, I'll accept it. But @MarkAmery's comment suggests that there isn't general consensus yet. I agree that I wouldn't want to flag a reviewer without first going through their previous reviews myself, but does anyone have any further comments on this answer?

Comment: This answer assumes OP has succumbed to the XY problem, but I don't see it that way. I think the question, as expressed by the subject line, is a legitimate one. And a legitimate answer to that question might be "that's not important enough to warrant mod attention or a proper mechanism to address; if an edit deserved rejection but was rejected for the wrong reason, just let sleeping dogs lie".

Comment: To be clear, I think it's absolutely useful to point to the Meta.SE question on robo-reviewers. I would have incorporated it into an answer that addresses the title question in its own right, and then for completeness adds something along the lines of "if it *does* turn out to be a pattern of robo-reviewing rather than an isolated case, then *this* applies".

Answer (score 0):

Edit rejections are not like close votes. If the editor (or anyone) looks at their suggestion history, they will only see "approved edit" or "rejected edit", which is a link to the review.

Everyone sees the same thing when visiting a review (unless the edit is still in the queue): a list of reviewers and their decisions. It's possible that 3 different edit rejection reasons were given:

> [image]

I think that some edits can be bad for more than one reason. The rejections above were for an edit that added a tag; however, the edit summary was the start of something that should have been a comment or a new question (thus my rejection reason).

---

There are several things that you can do if you feel the other rejection reasons are inadequate or wrong:

- Reject with the right reason

  - Always use the "spam or vandalism" reason if it's spam or vandalism
  - Filling out the "causes harm" custom reason helps otherwise
- `@Ping` the editor and tell them what's wrong with the edit.

  - I would only do this if the editor is proposing multiple edits with the same problem

I would not worry about reviewers rejecting with the wrong reason if the edit should be rejected anyway.