# Could I have made a better edit than just fixing a link?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I don't suggest edits very often, so after my edit was approved I looked at the [edit review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10255679) to see what had transpired. I was surprised to see a dissenting opinion on what I thought was a very uncontroversial edit.

I merely updated a link to point to the new location of its content. I had already searched for it because I wanted to read the content and the link was broken. I figured others might save some time from my edit.

What should I take from the knowledge that one of four reviewers rejected my edit for 'deviates from the original intent'? Could I have made a better edit? Should I discount this criticism as invalid? If it's not a valid criticism, does that happen often?

Comment: Essentially this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310693/792066

Comment: Oh, I remember that one along with checking the link before/after. I thought that was a perfectly fine edit. Correcting a link that's broken is definitely a very valuable edit, no matter how small (and actually small here is very tasteful). I think that person who rejected is probably just trying to grind for badges in a way that avoids failing that kind of robo reviewer test the site puts up -- a cheat/exploit.

Answer (score 2):

It's an invalid criticism. There's very little you can do about it, and unfortunately it happens fairly often; when I was reviewing suggested edits more often, for every four or five bad edits on the fast track to robo-approval I saw a good edit with at least one bad rejection reason. (And ten or twenty unexceptional edits I didn't bother with.)

If you get unlucky and wind up with a perfectly good edit, just try again (possibly tweaking the edit summary for more clarity), but only *once* with that edit. That's enough to give you a fair shake at a better set of reviewers without clogging the queue throwing edits at the wall to see which will stick.

Answer (score 2):

This is an ongoing problem on StackOverflow and one that goes against the whole point of community editing.

Allowing anyone to edit anyone elses question or answer as a fairly contreversial move in the begining of stack overflow, but it is designed to allow exactly what you did.  If you find an out of date link you can update it, job done.

Unfortunately some user who have sufficient rep to review the edit queue don't understand the benefit of a very small change such as what you made.  Obviously it is import edits are monitored to deal with spam, but there is no reason a valid url update should be rejected.

Keep making edits, and even better work on your rep to get to 2,000 so you can edit without peer review.

Keep up the good work.